# AS3 Get exact size of movieclip if stage scaled

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, resize, scale

How do I get an exact width and height of a MovieClip if it was scaled on stage resize?

for example if I have:

```
stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, checkSize);
function checkSize(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace(mc.width);
}
```

It will always output the same width and height no matter how big or small the stage is. Is there anyway to get exact current size?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The current size of your MovieClip is as shown by your `trace()` I don't think there's a way to determine (easily) how many pixels down and across your MovieClip is with `EXACT_FIT` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try using either mc.measuredWidth, or mc.width * mc.scaleX != 1? mc.scaleX:scaleX;